# PHP Display post variables

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm looking for a bit of help and a bit of an explanation here.

I have created an HTML form with several input fields and some very basic PHP validation when POSTing the inputs.  My validation just checks to see if the field has data and if not, it prompts the user to enter data in the field by displaying an error.  My hope is ultimately to POST these inputs, check them against a database, and if they aren't there, then add them to the database. But, this is not my issue at hand.

Currently, my objective is to take all of the inputs in my field that I want to POST and to display them in a field below my error display area.  I had hoped to just echo the data but for some reason, not all of the entered data appears.

Of the 5 entry fields in the code below, 4 are basic input fields and one is a text area.  If i enter anything into the basic input fields, only the last input will echo in my display area.  If i enter something into field 1 and leave the rest blank, field 1 will display.  Also, if I enter something into the text area, it will always display.  Finally, my PHP validation does not appear to work with my textarea type input (labeled 'note') and will not return an error if the 'note' input is left blank.Can anyone explain: (1) How do I fix it so that all 5 inputs display in the display div?; (2) Why does this happen?; (3) why is no error returned if the text area (labeled 'note') is left blank?

Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
//form validation for general entry form

    // define variables and set to empty values
    $clientErr = $matterErr = $dateErr = $timeErr = $noteErr= "";
    $client = $matter = $date = $time = $note = "";


    //on post, check to see if variable is empty. if not empty
    //parse it and assign value back to variable name

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $complete = true;
        $postArray = [];


        if (empty($_POST["client"])) {
            $clientErr = "*A client name is required. ";
            $complete = false;
        }else {


            $client = test_input($_POST["client"]);
            //$postArray[] =  $client;
        }


        if (empty($_POST["matter"])) {
            $matterErr = "*A matter name is required. ";
            $complete = false;
        }else {
            $client = test_input($_POST["matter"]);
        }


        if (empty($_POST["date"])) {
            $dateErr = "*A date is required. ";
            $complete = false;
        }else {
            $client = test_input($_POST["date"]);
        }


        if (empty($_POST["time"])) {
            $timeErr = "*A time entry is required. ";
            $complete = false;
        }else {
            $client = test_input($_POST["time"]);
        }

        if (empty($_POST["note"])) {
            $noteErr = "*A note is required. ";
            $complete = false;
        } else {
            $note = test_input($_POST["note"]);
        }

    } 

    function test_input($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    }
?>


<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" >

    <label for="client">Client:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder = "Enter Client Name" name="client"> * 

    <label for="matter">Matter:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder = "Enter Matter Name" name="matter"> *

    <label for="date">Date:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder = "Enter Date" name="date"> *

    <label for="time">Time:</label> 
    <input type="text" placeholder ="Time to nearest tenth hour" name="time"> *

    <label for="note">Note:</label>
    <textarea name="note" placeholder ="Enter Any Notes" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea> 

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submitbutton">

 </form>  


<div class="errorDiv">
    <?php 
        echo $clientErr;
        echo $matterErr; 
        echo $dateErr;
        echo $timeErr; 
    ?>      

</div>

<div class ="displayDiv">
    <?php

            echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
            echo $client;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $matter;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $date;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $time;
            echo "<br>";
            echo $note;



    ?>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php
    //form validation for general entry form

        // define variables and set to empty values
        $clientErr = $matterErr = $dateErr = $timeErr = $noteErr= "";
        $client = $matter = $date = $time = $note = "";


        //on post, check to see if variable is empty. if not empty
        //parse it and assign value back to variable name

        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            $complete = true;
            $postArray = [];


            if (empty($_POST["client"])) {
                $clientErr = "*A client name is required. ";
                $complete = false;
            }else {


                $client = test_input($_POST["client"]);
                //$postArray[] =  $client;
            }


            if (empty($_POST["matter"])) {
                $matterErr = "*A matter name is required. ";
                $complete = false;
            }else {
                $matter = test_input($_POST["matter"]);  //remove $client and assign value to $matter
            }


            if (empty($_POST["date"])) {
                $dateErr = "*A date is required. ";
                $complete = false;
            }else {
                $date = test_input($_POST["date"]); //remove $client and assign value to $date
            }


            if (empty($_POST["time"])) {
                $timeErr = "*A time entry is required. ";
                $complete = false;
            }else {
                $time = test_input($_POST["time"]); //remove $client and assign value to $time
            }

            if (empty($_POST["note"])) {
                $noteErr = "*A note is required. ";
                $complete = false;
            } else {
                $note = test_input($_POST["note"]);
            }

        } 

        function test_input($data) {
          $data = trim($data);
          $data = stripslashes($data);
          $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
          return $data;
        }
    ?>


    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" >

        <label for="client">Client:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder = "Enter Client Name" name="client"> * 

        <label for="matter">Matter:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder = "Enter Matter Name" name="matter"> *

        <label for="date">Date:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder = "Enter Date" name="date"> *

        <label for="time">Time:</label> 
        <input type="text" placeholder ="Time to nearest tenth hour" name="time"> *

        <label for="note">Note:</label>
        <textarea name="note" placeholder ="Enter Any Notes" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea> 

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submitbutton">

     </form>  


    <div class="errorDiv">
        <?php 
            echo $clientErr;
            echo $matterErr; 
            echo $dateErr;
            echo $timeErr; 
            echo $noteErr;  // echo noteerror here.........
        ?>      

    </div>

    <div class ="displayDiv">
        <?php

                echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
                echo $client;
                echo "<br>";
                echo $matter;
                echo "<br>";
                echo $date;
                echo "<br>";
                echo $time;
                echo "<br>";
                echo $note;



        ?>
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Here you assign all values to single variable `$client` and echo all different variable so assign value to particular variable like `$matter`, `$date`, `$time`. And you forget to echo `$noteerror` in error messsages.

Comment: Thank you for catching this.  This is the entire complete answer.

Comment: Yep, beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 4):

You copy and pasted your `else` block, didn't you? In each block you assign the value to `$client` and thereby overwrite it with each new `$_POST` value. Change the other assignments to `$client` to `$time` or appropriate and try that.

For example this

```
$client = test_input($_POST["date"]);
```

should probably be

```
$date = test_input($_POST["date"]);
```

Comment: I absolutely did. thank you for the catch.  That answers questions 1 and 2.  Any chance you know why 3 is still a problem for me?

Comment: Let me run a test, I suspect that `<textarea>` will always submit a value. You may have to check that `$_POST['note'] !== ''` instead of `empty()`.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you assigning all the values to same $client variable? It has to be replaced with different variables.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $complete = true;
    $postArray = [];


    if (empty($_POST["client"])) {
        $clientErr = "*A client name is required. ";
        $complete = false;
    }else {


        $client = test_input($_POST["client"]);
        //$postArray[] =  $client;
    }


    if (empty($_POST["matter"])) {
        $matterErr = "*A matter name is required. ";
        $complete = false;
    }else {
        $matter= test_input($_POST["matter"]);
    }


    if (empty($_POST["date"])) {
        $dateErr = "*A date is required. ";
        $complete = false;
    }else {
        $date= test_input($_POST["date"]);
    }


    if (empty($_POST["time"])) {
        $timeErr = "*A time entry is required. ";
        $complete = false;
    }else {
        $time= test_input($_POST["time"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["note"])) {
        $noteErr = "*A note is required. ";
        $complete = false;
    } else {
        $note = test_input($_POST["note"]);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you you are correct but the user above caught this so I will be selecting his answer as the correct one.